# Passing line of code as argument into function

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am looking to pass a line of code into a function I am calling in c# with the intention to optimise my code and attempt to learn something new.  I am familiar with using strings, ints, floats, booleans as I have shown in my code.

The idea is to call a function on a button click that stops a script and begins a script again.  Without the function this code is working:

```
public void PlayOnClick()
{
    if(count != 1)
    {
        m_animator.GetComponent<Animator>().Play("Scale");
        d_animator.GetComponent<Animator>().Play("CloseUp");
        ((MovieTexture)MovieOne.GetComponent<Renderer>().material.mainTexture).Play();
        Dialyser.GetComponent<RotationByMouseDrag>().enabled = false;
        count = 1;
    }
    else
    {
        m_animator.GetComponent<Animator>().Play("Scale");
        d_animator.GetComponent<Animator>().Play("ScaleDown");
        ((MovieTexture)MovieOne.GetComponent<Renderer>().material.mainTexture).Stop();
        Dialyser.GetComponent<RotationByMouseDrag>().enabled = true;
        count = 0;
    }     
}
```

However I believe this can be shortened.  I have got this so far:

```
void Lock(string A, string B, ? C, bool D, int E)
{
    m_animator.GetComponent<Animator>().Play(A);
    d_animator.GetComponent<Animator>().Play(B);
    C;
    Dialyser.GetComponent<RotationByMouseDrag>().enabled = D;
    count = E;

}
```

In function C I would want to pass the following line when pressed once:

```
((MovieTexture)MovieOne.GetComponent<Renderer>().material.mainTexture).Stop();
```

And have it change to this when pressed again:

```
((MovieTexture)MovieOne.GetComponent<Renderer>().material.mainTexture).Play();
```

I have come across eval - but I believe that is just for javascript and could be quite processor intensive.  I have looked into parsing the line as a string.

I am currently coming up trumps on searches and on attempts.  Could anyone shed some light on this for me?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you are looking for is called delegates, or function pointers in c++ terms.

You can find more on [delegates](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/articles/csharp/programming-guide/delegates/) here.

[Actions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/018hxwa8(v=vs.110).aspx) might feel more quicker to code with.

Basically, you can pass a reference to a method you want to execute. The signature of the method should be exactly the same as parameter type declared in the method. So if you expect to pass and run a piece of code that does not return any value, you could use Action type, without any type parameters. For example

```
class A {
    void printAndExecute(String textToPrint, Action voidMethodToExecute) {
        Debug.Log(textToPrint);
        voidMethodToExecute();
    }
}

class B : MonoBehaviour {
    void Start() {
        new A().printAndExecute("SAY", sayHello);
    }

    void sayHello() {
        Debug.Log("Hello!");
    }
}
```

Hope it helps

Comment: thank you - this was what I was after.  Much appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

You have to pass an [`Action`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.action(v=vs.110).aspx) type or a custom delegate :

```
void Lock(string A, string B, System.Action C, bool D, int E)
{
    m_animator.GetComponent<Animator>().Play(A);
    d_animator.GetComponent<Animator>().Play(B);
    C();
    Dialyser.GetComponent<RotationByMouseDrag>().enabled = D;
    count = E;    
}

// ...

Lock("Scale", "CloseUp", ((MovieTexture)MovieOne.GetComponent<Renderer>().material.mainTexture).Play, false, 1 ) ;
```

Comment: Thank you - I have upvoted you and your answer was great.  However I had to base the answer on who got in first.  Best wishes and hope to hear from you again.